# php array keys contain const value

Tags: php

I have a php program like below:

```
const DATE = '2016/1/1';
$chargingRecord = array('calculate date:'.self::DATE => 5.00);
```

This code cannot run successfully when php version is 5.4, but didn't show any error in php 7.0, which I had tried,Is there any idea or problem in this? thanks!

Comment: can you show us your whole class code ?

Comment: [Seems to work just fine for all of PHP 5 and 7](https://3v4l.org/A9205), voting to close as not reproducible.